# Making static assets not go through SPA

Tags: nginx

I on a single page application with the following setup:

```
location / {
    root    /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

I would like for all static files, in /static/ to not go through the application. Example, for a 404, serve nginx's 404 and not the application 404.

I tried the following:

```
location /static/ {
    autoindex on;
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/static;
}

location / {
    root    /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

But to no avail.

Comment: Do not put `root` inside the `location` block. See [Pitfalls and Common Mistakes](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/).